# How to return a value to client application from WebAPI but at the same time some other operation needs to be performed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI method as under

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddSubProduct")]
public string InsertSubProduct(SubProduct subproduct)
{
   try
   {
      subProductRepository.InsertSubProduct(subproduct);

      // This message must be returned to the client application as soon
      // as the product is created
      subproduct.ToString();

      // This will happen parallely 
      DoSomethingElse(subproduct);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }
}
```

As can be figured out that `subproduct.Tostring()` will be first sent to the client application immediately (as soon as the Product is created) and **DoSomethingElse** will work independently (though the current implementation is not like that, we have to do it). As can be figured out that I cannot use a **return statement** here.

How will I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to queue work on a background thread. I suggest using [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're using .NET 4.5.2. If you're on a previous version, use[`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks). Both will register their work with the ASP.NET runtime:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddSubProduct")]
public string InsertSubProduct(SubProduct subproduct)
{
    subProductRepository.InsertSubProduct(subproduct);

    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(cancellationToken =>
                                               DoSomethingElse(subproduct));
    return subproduct.ToString();
}
```

If you're going to be doing this often with concurrent requests, you should consider queuing up and have a single thread dequeue and process them. If persistence is of matter here, you'll need to choose a different route.

Side note - don't catch exceptions you can't handle. Especially, don't use `throw ex`, you lose the stacktrace.

Comment: your solution is very nice, but I am using framework 4.5.1 and QueueBackgroundWorkItem is applicable from 4.5.2 version... What is the alternative for that?

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar As I said in my answer, if you're using pre .NET 4.5.2, use the `BackgroundTaskManager`. I even provided a link :)